# QGIS - Attachment widget: copy file, use camera?

Tags: qgis-3, qfield

With a QGIS Project in QField, you can configure the Attachment Widget to store the picture you take (or select) in a folder together with the project.

- Is it possible with QGIS to use a built-in camera with the widget? (rather than taking the picture, browsing to the directory)
- Is it possible to copy a selected file to a folder stored with the project?

Comment: like https://vimeo.com/173774749 ?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the same feature in QGis Desktop (for Windows). Pick files or use a built-in camera (tablet), and store it within a subfolder where the project is stored.

Comment: Look at this:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363648/how-to-attach-pictures-saved-in-relative-path