# How to attach pictures saved in relative path

Tags: qgis, qfield, widget, attachments, portable

I have a QGIS project saved under `G:\USER\xyz\projects\QGIS.qgz`

In the same folder is a subfolder `Pictures`. My layer contains a column with the picture names (For example: `101.jpg`). The picture `101.jpg` is within this subfolder `Pictures`. How can I tell QGIS to connect this picture name in the layer's column to that actual picture in the subfolder?

[image: My configuration]

In the screenshot you can see my configuration - I think it should work like this? Relative path checked and in the default path field I wrote the name of the subfolder. It is not working though. Any thoughts? I want to achieve that the whole project folder is portable so I can use it with QField.

Comment: I never used the attachment widget, but since Pictures is the folder name, have you tried to change the Storage Mode to Directory paths?

Comment: that does not work unfortunately - i think that option should be changed to Directory Paths if the columnof the layer contains full paths and not file names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

With this expression it takes the project path and adds the desired subfolder to it:

file_path(@project_path) + '\Pictures\'

[image]

<s>Unfortunately this does not work for QField</s>

As with the newest version of QField Sync, this is solved.